# Call custom functions onclicking the radio buttons with changing the style(Background image OnClick function)

Tags: css

In my application I need to style the radio buttons with images.  To do that I need to implement 'OnClick' functionality for setting the background image.

I am using following code snippet to do this.

```
element.onclick = function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            var siblings = getInputsByName(this.name);

            for(var q = 0; q < siblings.length; q++) {
                siblings[q].dummy.className = "NFRadio";
            }
            this.dummy.className = "NFRadio NFh";
        }
    }
```

But in some cases I need to do additional operations by selecting or changing the radio buttons.

Is there any way to call custom function on selecting or clicking the radio button addition to above functionality.

Please give suggestions..

Comment: Add some related code and CSS. If possible, show some example of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the browser you are using you have only a marginal or no influence on the style in which checkboxes and radio buttons are displayed. And that's why frameworks such as jQuery replace them with images. There is not much you can do to style default form elements. And for a good reason: Usability and security. The user can easily recognize default form elements if they have a similar style everywhere.

Comment: Yep, that says it all. If you decide to use jQuery then this is a nice plugin to use [http://gokercebeci.com/dev/forma](http://gokercebeci.com/dev/forma)